# strange catch clause... C++

Tags: c++

What is this catch clause??

```
STD_CATCH_ALL_with_kMETHODID(...)
```

Its used in a python interpreter extension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about right-click and select *Go To Declaration* (using Visual Studio). You may try *Go To Definition* as well. If you cannot find it, it means you need to include a header where this macro is defined.

Comment: Can you compile your code that uses this macro? Or you can't because its definition cannot be found and this is what you've posted your question?

Answer (score 2):

It's a macro so you need to look in your headers. An IDE should be able to go to its definition
or look at the after preprocesser expansion. -E command line option on gcc